# transformation of OMOP ontological instances to OMOP relational database

Tags: java, postgresql, rdf

Basically, I am following the approach as mentioned [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5937227/) to transform (or map) the source data available in relation tables to OMOP data model and then store it to OMOP tables.

I used D2RQ tool to get source data from various tables in RDF format and applied N3 rules (for mapping source columns to omop tables'columns) via EYE reasoner and transformed source RDF data to OMOP ontological instances.

Now, I have data (as an instance of OMOP ontology) which need to be stored in OMOP CDM tables which I created in PostgreSQL DB.

So, any guidance on how can I store these data to OMOP CDM tables?

Comment: why in a relational database and not a triple store? and what means "how"? create a table and add the data or not? I mean, which other choice do you have? It's your task to decide on a table schema. A single triple table is obviously the most simple way. Or use a table per distinct predicate in the data. Or ... and so on and so furth

Comment: And what happens after you loaded the data? You want to run SQL queries on the data?

Comment: More detail is definitely needed -- about what you're really trying to achieve, and to what purpose -- as "put it in a table" won't necessarily deliver your desired results. See [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Your title says "*like* PostgreSQL" but your question actually seems to *require* PostgreSQL. You *might* be better off with a hybrid DBMS that handles both SQL and RDF/SPARQL data and queries, and makes both available to tools that understand either, such as [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) (from my employer).

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with the data. Technically, all you need is one three-column table (with columns _subject, predicate, object_.) If you're just persisting the data, with no queries other than full retrieval, it's good enough. But that's unlikely to be your use case.

Comment: I have update the above description to make it more clear.

Comment: Am I able to explain the problem? Any guidance from any one?